# Android: Unbale to save boolean in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, boolean, sharedpreferences

Hey guys I am unable to save a boolean value using SharedPreferences. The value is ALWAYS true for some reasons. Here is how I save the value:

```
public static void setSharedPreference(Context ctx, String keyValue, boolean value){
    SharedPreferences sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences(Constants._preferencesName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(keyValue,value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

And this is how I get it back:

```
 public static boolean getBooleanPreference(Context ctx, String keyValue){
    boolean prefValue;
    SharedPreferences sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences(Constants._preferencesName, ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefValue = sp.getBoolean(keyValue, false);

    return prefValue;
}
```

What is wrong?!

Comment: you sure you are using the same `_preferencesName` and `keyValue` in both calls? 'cos I am in doubts a bit...

Comment: yep I am positive about it

Comment: As you can see _preferenceName is a constant so ... its always the same! And Context is the same in the two methods

Comment: default value is false. if true is being return by sp.getBoolean(K,false) its definitely storing

Comment: see my answer. If i am right, then it can be you are reading value written some time ago

Comment: Yes as kay has mentioned since default is false you are storing the preference true somewhere .

Comment: When you get the value back, why not use "SharedPreferences sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences(Constants._preferencesName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);" instead of "SharedPreferences sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences(Constants._preferencesName, ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);"

Nothing is wrong in the rest of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is syntactically correct, but I suspect you are passing different `Context` while saving than you are passing while reading from prefs. This will result in accessing **different** shared preferences storage. This is especially easy to step on if you are doing your writes and reads in different activities and decide to pass `this` as context. Unless there's a reason for doing so then you most likely want to reach your preferences from anywhere in your app then use always application context instead (`getApplicationContext()`).

Comment: Oh my god ... you were right I was setting the same preference in 2 different classes. Meaning2 different context. Thank you so much for helping me find my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct in your code.

The **ONLY** possibility of a mistake is when you are calling these methods. Please use `getApplicationContext()` while putting and retrieving data.

And please do a "**Clear data**" for the app and start with a clean SharedPreference.